# How to interact with Azure AD B2C custom User Attributes via Microsoft Graph PowerShell SDK?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, microsoft-graph-sdks, powershell-7.0

I have added a custom User Attribute named `Company Name` via:

`Azure AD B2C` > `User attributes`

so that this information can be returned in the identity token after successful sign in.

I want to update these values for each user in the Azure AD B2C tenant.

As I understand it:

- I cannot update these values via Azure Portal
- The only way to update these values is [via Microsoft Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42795928), specifically these methods:

  - [Get user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get)
  - [Update user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update)

I don't want to have to create an application just to be able to perform this basic administrative task.

So I am looking at:

[Microsoft Graph PowerShell SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/get-started)

I installed the [Microsoft Graph PowerShell SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/get-started) in PowerShell 7.

I was prompted to sign in via the browser after running this command:

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "User.Read.All","Group.ReadWrite.All"
```

At this point I was confused which credentials to login with.

I logged in using my 'home tenant' Azure AD credentials.

(i.e the admin credentials of the Azure AD tenant from which I created the Azure AD B2C tenant - which then automatically created a *guest* account in the B2C tenant with the user principal name of `info_my-home-tenant.onmicrosoft.com#EXT#@my-dev-tenant.onmicrosoft.com`).

I made the decision because I don't think I *have* any Azure AD B2C credentials.

(to access Azure AD B2C when I am logged into Azure Portal with my Azure AD credentials, I just click on 'switch directory').

I then ran:

```
Get-MgUser
```

And it, predictably, returned the users from my home Azure AD tenant, not the Azure AD B2C tenant.

So my question is:

In PowerShell 7, with the `Microsoft Graph PowerShell SDK` installed, how do I sign in so that I can interact with the Azure AD B2C tenant users, rather than my 'home' directory tenant users.

**EDIT:**

I started trying to follow the process described here:

[Use app-only authentication with the Microsoft Graph PowerShell SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/app-only)

The [first step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/app-only?view=graph-powershell-1.0&tabs=azure-portal#certificate) is:

> You'll need an X.509 certificate installed in your user's trusted store on the machine where you'll run the script

I created an Application Registration, however in the `Certificates & secrets` section it says:

> Please note certificates cannot be used to authenticate against Azure AD B2C.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree this is tricky.

Below are the steps you can use to successfully sign in to Azure AD B2C using Microsoft Graph SDK, and update a user's custom attribute value.

This post is divided into three sections:

- Solution Summary (to get an idea of the scope before diving into the details)
- Variables (which lists the variable values required and where to find them)
- Commands (which lists the commands required)

This post assumes we have a custom attribute named `Company Name` defined in Azure AD B2C:

[image]

---

**PowerShell Microsoft Graph SDK Reference**

To orientate yourself, here is the link to the `Microsoft.Graph.Users` section:

[Microsoft.Graph.Users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.users)

---

**Summary**

The solution requires the definition of 4 variables and 5 commands that will reference them:

Variables:

- `azure_ad_b2c_tenant_id`
- `extensions_app_id`
- `custom_attribute_property`
- `user_id`

Commands:

Make a connection:

```
Connect-MgGraph -TenantId "<azure_ad_b2c_tenant_id>" -Scopes "User.ReadWrite.All"
```

Sanity check - list all users:

```
Get-MgUser | Format-List  ID, DisplayName, UserPrincipalName
```

Sanity check - view existing value of custom attribute for single user:

```
$existingUser = Get-MgUser -UserId "<user-id>" -Property "id,extension_<your-extensions-app-application-id>_CompanyName"
$existingUser.AdditionalProperties | Format-List
```

Update a user's custom attribute:

```
$params = @{extension_<your-extensions-app-application-id>_CompanyName='Test Company'}
Update-MgUser -UserId "<user-id>" -BodyParameter $params
```

Verify the update:

```
$existingUser = Get-MgUser -UserId "<user-id>" -Property "id,extension_<your-extensions-app-application-id>_CompanyName"
$existingUser.AdditionalProperties | Format-List
```

---

**Variables**

Below are the variables that will be referenced and where to find them.

You might want to grab them at the start of the process so you can easily reference them later.

`azure_ad_b2c_tenant_id`

- `Azure AD B2C directory` > `Azure AD` > `Tenant ID`

[image]

`extensions_app_id`

- `Azure AD B2C` > `App registrations` > `[ select 'All applications' ]`
- Click on the item named:
- `b2c-extensions-app. Do not modify. Used by AADB2C for storing user data.`
- Copy the `Application (client) ID` value
- Remove the dashes from this value when using it in PowerShell

[image]

[image]

`custom_attribute_property`
This is a string of concatenated values with this syntax:

```
extension_<your-extensions-app-application-id>_<your-custom-attribute>
```

For example:  `extension_lalala1234etc_CompanyName`

`user_id`

- `Azure AD B2C` > `Users` > `[ click on desired user ]` > `Object ID`

[image]

---

**Commands**

*01.  Connect to your Azure AD B2C tenant*

```
Connect-MgGraph -TenantId "<azure_ad_b2c_tenant_id>" -Scopes "User.ReadWrite.All"
```

This will prompt you to login with your Azure AD home tenant credentials.

[image]

*02.  Sanity check - list all users to confirm you are in the right tenant*

```
Get-MgUser   

// you can make the results prettier by using Format-List and defining the columns you want displayed   
Get-MgUser | Format-List  ID, DisplayName, UserPrincipalName
```

*03.  Sanity check - see what the value of the custom attribute currently is for all users and a single user*

```
// all users - these do not work:  
Get-MgUser | Format-List  ID, extension_<your-extensions-app-application-id>_CompanyName
Get-MgUser -Property "id,extension_<your-extensions-app-application-id>_CompanyName"

// single user - these do not work:  
Get-MgUser -UserId "<user-id>" | Format-List  ID, DisplayName, UserPrincipalName, extension_<your-extensions-app-application-id>_CompanyName
Get-MgUser -UserId "<user-id>" -Property "id,extension_<your-extensions-app-application-id>_CompanyName"

// single user - this works:
$existingUser = Get-MgUser -UserId "<user-id>" -Property "id,extension_<your-extensions-app-application-id>_CompanyName"
$existingUser.AdditionalProperties | Format-List
```

*04.  Update a single user's custom attribute*

```
$params = @{extension_<your-extensions-app-application-id>_CompanyName='Test Company'}
Update-MgUser -UserId "<user-id>" -BodyParameter $params
```

*05.  Verify the update was made*

```
$existingUser = Get-MgUser -UserId "<user-id>" -Property "id,extension_<your-extensions-app-application-id>_CompanyName"
$existingUser.AdditionalProperties | Format-List
```

[image]

The decoded `idToken` that is returned after sign in will look like this:

[image]

Or, if signing in via an identity provider (in this case the home AD tenant), the decoded `idToken` will look like this:

[image]

Comment: thank you, i just have to make some time to test this today, but i think it will work, and will accept answer after i have tested it.

Comment: Thank you, please let me know the final result, fingers crossed!

Comment: Quick related question - when adding a custom attribute via `Azure AD B2C` > `User Attributes`, what _type_ of extension is it?  `Extension attribute`, `Directory extension`, `Schema extension` or `Open extension`?  (see: [Choose an extension type for your application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-overview?tabs=powershell#choose-an-extension-type-for-your-application))  I am troubleshooting commands in the PowerShell Graph SDK and there seem to be various considerations depending on what _type_ of extension it is.

Comment: I added some screenshots to your answer to flesh out the process a bit more as I found your answer very helpful.  I was unable to figure out how to return ALL users with the custom attribute displaying from a single command.  I included my attempts in `step 03` with the prefix 'these do not work'.  If you know how to do this, it would be great if you could add it to the answer.  I spent the whole day googling how to do it, but couldn't find a way that was specific to the PowerShell Microsoft Graph SDK.

Comment: Just doing research from my mobile, assuming this custom attribute is of type ‘directory extension’ it seems like it is possible to return it directly, but there is no snippet provided for the PowerShell SDK - 
[Retrieve a directory extension property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-overview?tabs=powershell#retrieve-a-directory-extension-property)

Comment: Yes, correct, this is directory extension. Unfortunately MS does not provide any snippets so this is more tricky to implement with PowerShell and Graph SDK.
However I can confirm that this is directory extension as I also used C# snipped which is for directory extension type and it worked as expected:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-overview?tabs=csharp#add-a-directory-extension-property-to-a-target-object
Thank you for adding more details to my answer, looks good.